# What word would be a good replacement for the use of "licensee"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

A lot of my clients do not natively speak English. Because of this, confusion has arisen over what is meant by the term *licensee*.

Each product requires its own unique license key and the licensee's name entered. The non-natively English speaking clients tend to enter another license key which they purchased from us — which means the product cannot be activated.

I need a different word to refer to the name of the license holder (the licensee's name) to avoid the confusion that arises.

Comment: Hiya. I don't have an answer for you, just a little advice to consider: I recommend leading with the notion in the last sentence (so people don't think yer just gripin').

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Updated. Thanks for the advice. It makes sense.

Comment: Your sentence "the client must enter the licensee's name" implicitly suggests that the client and the licensee are two different people. Sometimes they are, but I'd guess most of the time they're not. If you have a website that gives the same impression, it's not too surprising that people are confused.

Comment: A quick guess would be that they simply miss the second e and read the word as ‘license’, which would of course be expected to be their license key.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the English language. 

Comment: Why don't you just ask the clients? They *know for a fact* what their thought process is. We can only guess. Perhaps they are all drunk.

Comment: How about "License-holder's name"?

Answer (score 3):

Only a power higher than us can say *why* some people do not understand the meaning of the word licensee. But really, that's irrelevant. Your real question is about user experience, not people's understanding of vocabulary.

There's probably not a single word that you could use as a synonym for licensee. If you can use more than one word, "License Holder" might work nicely.

Comment: There is a legal principle that ambiguity is resolved against the drafter.  While you are not describing an ambiguity, you are describing a failure of communication.  I suspect that a single word to replace licensee will not solve your problem and that an overall re-write is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try to understand the intended meaning of the term *licence* aka *license*. Despite the US spelling, I need to use the British spelling to allow me to differentiate between the noun and the verb.

A driver's licence or driving licence is when you pay a jurisdictional govt for the **permission** to drive. You do not have ownership of the road, and that permission can be revoked by the licensor at any time.

You pay fees to be licensed to drive, rather than to be given the ownership to drive. Therefore, logically, a licensee does not ***own*** a licence, but ***holds*** a licence. A licence may require a one time fee or recurring fees paid by the licensee to be conferred the ***right to use***.

This is the actual set of dynamics that we could trace back to 40 years ago when software companies were gradually increasingly realising the legal advantage of issuing a *licence to right to use* rather than a *certificate or declaration of ownership*.

The colloquial use of the word *owner* rather than the legal term *holder* of the licence is the mother of the confusion. Legally, you the licensor, are the *owner* of the software product. In more stringent cases, you the licensor, could even be the *owner of the licence*. You merely accept fees to disburse the right to use your software either

- for window of time
- or permanently
- either of the above only on a particular device or only on a specified type or range of devices, or only on a specified mode of use.

It would be truly confusing if you yourself do not understand the implication of a licence, and do not explain the terms of your licensing. No one would understand the implication of the licence but you the licensor. If you had simply copied licensing description from, say, a Microsoft product, you might need to consult a lawyer what your and your customers' rights and liabilities are.

Two causes of confusion.

- Many people may think that you, being the licensor, are the owner of the licence. It is up to you to say who owns the licence and to behold the legal implications thereof. Because many people, having acclimated to the shenanigans of holding a licence rather than ownership of a product, know by hard and by heart that you are the owner of the product being licensed.
- 2ndly, there are two sets of licences here. One originating from you and another originating from the product with which your product co-operates. Which licence are you referring to? Your language may seem plain and simple to you, but many of us are sequentially dyslexic or even autistic (programmers apparently have the highest incidence of high-functioning autism) which gives us shorter than usual attention spans or dyslexia in interpreting the order and sequence of events and description.

It clearly falls on you to explain your role, your customers' roles and the intention in licensing your product.